# DELETE with GROUP BY and aggregate conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that includes a foreign key and a DATETIME timestamp. I want to delete all rows where the timestamp is later than the beginning of the day of the final timestamp, but for each item separately.

Logically I want something like this:

```
 DELETE FROM Entries
 WHERE StartTime > CONVERT(Date,MAX(StartTime))
 GROUP BY ItemId;
```

But I can't use GROUP BY in a DELETE, nor can I use SUM() in a WHERE condition.

I can delete them one item at at time using a subquery like this:

```
 DELETE FROM Entries
 WHERE ItemId=@Id
 AND StartTime > (
   SELECT CONVERT(Date,MAX(StartTime)) FROM Entries
   WHERE ItemId=@Id
 )
```

But I want to delete for all items in a single query. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight but I want to delete for multiple ItemIds. My query above only handles one ItemId, applying the timestamp check separate for each item. My query above only handles a single ItemId at a time.

Comment: Never mind, I missed the `@Id` parameter in your query. I edited your query to make it what I thought it was when I typed up my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your query to not use `@Id`:

```
DELETE e
FROM Entries AS e
WHERE StartTime > (
   SELECT CONVERT(Date,MAX(StartTime)) FROM Entries ee
   WHERE ee.ItemId=e.Id
)
```

Answer (score 2):

For your query you can use

```
 DELETE FROM E
 FROM Entries E JOIN (
 SELECT ItemId, MAX(StartTime) st from Entries GROUP BY ItemId)E2
 ON E.ItemId=E2.ItemId 
 WHERE E.StartTime > CONVERT(Date,E2.st)
```